# Elastic/Kibana: support for plurals in query searches

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'll simplify my issue. Let's say I have an index with 3 documents I've created with Kibana:

```
PUT /test/vendors/1
{
  "type": "doctor",
  "name": "Phil",
  "works_in": [
      {
        "place": "Chicago"  
      },
      {
        "place": "New York"
      }
    ]
}

PUT /test/vendors/2
{
  "type": "lawyer",
  "name": "John",
  "works_in": [
      {
        "place": "Chicago"  
      },
      {
        "place": "New Jersey"
      }
    ]
}

PUT /test/vendors/3
{
  "type": "doctor",
  "name": "Jill",
  "works_in": [
      {
        "place": "Chicago"  
      }
    ]
}
```

Now I'm running a search:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "doctor in chicago", 
      "fields": [ "type", "place" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm getting a good response:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "vendors",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "type": "doctor",
          "name": "Phil",
          "works_in": [
            {
              "place": "Chicago"
            },
            {
              "place": "New York"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "vendors",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "type": "doctor",
          "name": "Jill",
          "works_in": [
            {
              "place": "Chicago"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now things begin to get problematic...

Changed the `doctor` to `doctors`

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "doctors in chicago", 
      "fields": [ "type", "place" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Zero results as `doctors` not found. Elastic doesn't know about plural vs. singular.

Change the query to  `New York`

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "doctor in new york", 
      "fields": [ "type", "place" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

But the response result set gives me the `doctor` in `Chicago` in addition to the `doctor` in `New York`. the fields are matched with OR...

Another interesting question is, what happens if someone uses`docs` or `physicians` or `health professionals` but means `doctor`. IS there a provision where I can teach Elasticsearch to funnel those into "doctor"?

Is there any pattern, way around these using elasticsearch alone? where I won't have to analyze the string for meaning in my own application which will then construct a complex exact elasticsearch query to match it?

I would appreciate any pointer in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the fields `type` and `place` are of [Text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) type with [Standard Analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html).

To manage singular/plurals, what you are looking for is called [Snowball Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-snowball-tokenfilter.html) which you would need to add to the mapping.

Another requirement that you've mentioned saying for e.g. `physicians` should also be equated as `doctor`, you need to make use of [Synonym Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html)

Below is how your mapping should be. Note that I've just added analyzer to `type`. You can make similar changes to the mapping to the other fields.

### Mapping

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{  
   "settings":{  
      "analysis":{  
         "analyzer":{  
            "my_analyzer":{  
               "tokenizer":"standard",
               "filter":[  
                  "lowercase",
                  "my_snow",
                  "my_synonym"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "my_snow":{  
               "type":"snowball",
               "language":"English"
            },
            "my_synonym":{  
               "type":"synonym",
               "synonyms":[  
                  "docs, physicians, health professionals, doctor"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{  
      "mydocs":{  
         "properties":{  
            "type":{  
               "type":"text",
               "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
            },
            "place":{  
               "type":"text",
               "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Notice how I've added the synonyms in the mapping itself, instead of that I'd suggest you to have the synonyms added in text file like below

```
{  
   "type":"synonym",
   "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt"
}
```

According to the link I've shared, it mentions that *the above configures a synonym filter, with a path of analysis/synonym.txt (relative to the config location).*

Hope it helps!

Comment: Worked very nicely. I had to remove my index and do this first before putting the documents back in there, but after that- it worked perfectly.  One problem down.... few more to go ;-)

Comment: Sorry I am still updating my answer. Didn't notice the question was also updated when I posted my answer. It would take a while but I'll update with what you are looking for.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!